# How to route call from VoiceBlue Next device to Asterisk Server

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I want to setup and IVR Menu i mean if a user calls to a particular GSM Number then the number should be redirected to Asterisk Server and the user needs to Get IVR Menu

I am using VoiceBlue Next firmware version 1.31.1.34.1 inserted working SIM Card

If i make a call to that particular number i am able to accept call,reject call and other options from VoiceBlueNext Web Interface.

I have made a SIP account in pjsip.conf file and created and extension as 100 in extensions.conf but unable to transfer the call to Asterisk Server

In asterisk server are there any other files to be changed or any settings in VoiceBlue Next

Answer (score 0):

There are not many details to understand your scenario, I have not used VoiceBlue but on Asterisk if you want to receive calls, from your VoiceBlue or any other provider. You have to do two things, one you have to register this peer to allow receive calls, or you can also set allowguest=yes(but very dangerous anyone can send you calls) or add peers at end of pjsip.conf file as little secure way.

Next, you need to add dialplan, suppose if you get any number _X will be any number, now you can put Dial your extension to receive any number from the provider.

As for sip client to call out you have to register peer and both must be in the same context.

Sending outgoing calls, now if you call any number beginning 6 and 7 they will be forwarded to VoiceBlue

```
exten=>_6XXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN:0}@10.0.0.20,,r)
exten=>_7XXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN:0}@10.0.0.20,,r)
```

for incoming please add following in your pjsip.conf

```
[VoiceBlueNext]
type=peer
host=10.0.0.20
username=voiceblue
secret=password
fromdomain=10.0.0.20
```

and in same file on top put following general section

```
[general]
port = 5060
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0
allowgues=no
context = sip
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
```

Notice I allowguest = no , so you must provide peer VoiceBlue peer information to receive calls, but if you want to test, make it yes and you will get calls without any security.

Comment: Hi thank you  have completed it, now i want information on How to call GSM numbers from asterisk server

Comment: You have to register your outbound trunk in sip configuration(pjsip.conf). And then you have to make dialplan within the same context(extensions.conf), so any call with mobile prefix will be forwarded to your outbound Gsm trunk.

Comment: Hi thanks kamal , you are telling about the call forwarding but i want to make the Outgoing call when the user presses any extensions

Comment: I told you to register outbound GSM trunk and when Sipclient call, it will be directed to that trunk.